# Stripe: Error "This application is not authorized to edit this account" while updating the account in stripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am very new the stripe & stripe API, right now am integrating the stripe into the django python server. I am able to create the customers & accounts. While updating the account with the bank token, I got an error "This application is not authorized to edit this account".
I am able to see the connected accounts on the connected accounts page in stripe dashboard.
Here is my code where I got the issue when `account.save()`

```
try:
    account = stripe.Account.retrieve(user_account_id)
    account.external_accounts = bank_account_token
    account.save()
except Exception as e:
    retrun e.message
return account
```

Comment: You should write to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email and include the ID of the account. They will be able to look at your logs and help you figure out the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, will do that now.

Comment: Yea, I did it & got the answer from Stripe. Thank you :)
`account = stripe.Account.retrieve(user_account_id) account.external_accounts.create(external_account=bank_accou‌​nt_token) account.save()`

Answer (score 2):

In my stripe experience, I had the same error like you.
I looked the stripe documentation carefully and I found that I used the wrong user type.
As you know, the stripe has 3 user types. standard, express, custom.
What I've done wrong is I used the standard account type. It was wrong.
Only custom account can have external_account.

So I changed the account type as 'custom' instead of 'standard'.

Here is my rails code below:

```
account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_account)
account.external_accounts.create(:external_account => params[:stripeToken])
account.save
```

Comment: Thank you very much, actually it fixed by updating the code in python

`account = stripe.Account.retrieve(user_account_id)        
 account.external_accounts.create(external_account=bank_account_token)
 account.save()
`